# Select rate for the most recent futures expiry multiple times SQL

Tags: mysql

Can you please help me with the following.

I have a table with 4 columns, and the following contents as an example:

```
maturity        date        ticker              rate
21/09/2021 0:00 9/07/2021   FUTPVOLUSD10YSEP21  4.476
22/03/2022 0:00 9/07/2021   FUTPVOLUSD10YMAR22  3.352
21/12/2021 0:00 9/07/2021   FUTPVOLUSD10YDEC21  4.856
21/12/2021 0:00 12/07/2021  FUTPVOLUSD10YDEC21  4.844
22/03/2022 0:00 12/07/2021  FUTPVOLUSD10YMAR22  3.352
21/09/2021 0:00 12/07/2021  FUTPVOLUSD10YSEP21  4.372
21/09/2021 0:00 13/07/2021  FUTPVOLUSD10YSEP21  4.323
22/03/2022 0:00 13/07/2021  FUTPVOLUSD10YMAR22  3.352
21/12/2021 0:00 13/07/2021  FUTPVOLUSD10YDEC21  4.633
21/12/2021 0:00 14/07/2021  FUTPVOLUSD10YDEC21  4.174
22/03/2022 0:00 14/07/2021  FUTPVOLUSD10YMAR22  3.352
21/09/2021 0:00 14/07/2021  FUTPVOLUSD10YSEP21  4.324
```

How can I extract a table where for each date I'll have the rate with the earliest maturity.

For example as of 14 July 2021 it's 4.324, as 21 September 2021 is the earliest maturity out of three available for this date.

Many thanks

Comment: It's always 21st September.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS n;

CREATE TABLE n
(maturity DATE 
,date DATE
,ticker VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,rate DECIMAL(5,3)
,PRIMARY KEY(ticker,date)
);

INSERT INTO n VALUES
(20210921, 20210709,  'SEP21' , 4.476),
(20220322, 20210709,  'MAR22' , 3.352),
(20211221, 20210709,  'DEC21' , 4.856),
(20211221, 20210712,  'DEC21' , 4.844),
(20220322, 20210712,  'MAR22' , 3.352),
(20210921, 20210712,  'SEP21' , 4.372),
(20210921, 20210713,  'SEP21' , 4.323),
(20220322, 20210713,  'MAR22' , 3.352),
(20211221, 20210713,  'DEC21' , 4.633),
(20211221, 20210714,  'DEC21' , 4.174),
(20220322, 20210714,  'MAR22' , 3.352),
(20210921, 20210714,  'SEP21' , 4.324);

SELECT * FROM n;
+------------+------------+--------+-------+
| maturity   | date       | ticker | rate  |
+------------+------------+--------+-------+
| 2021-09-21 | 2021-07-09 | SEP21  | 4.476 |
| 2022-03-22 | 2021-07-09 | MAR22  | 3.352 |
| 2021-12-21 | 2021-07-09 | DEC21  | 4.856 |
| 2021-12-21 | 2021-07-12 | DEC21  | 4.844 |
| 2022-03-22 | 2021-07-12 | MAR22  | 3.352 |
| 2021-09-21 | 2021-07-12 | SEP21  | 4.372 |
| 2021-09-21 | 2021-07-13 | SEP21  | 4.323 |
| 2022-03-22 | 2021-07-13 | MAR22  | 3.352 |
| 2021-12-21 | 2021-07-13 | DEC21  | 4.633 |
| 2021-12-21 | 2021-07-14 | DEC21  | 4.174 |
| 2022-03-22 | 2021-07-14 | MAR22  | 3.352 |
| 2021-09-21 | 2021-07-14 | SEP21  | 4.324 |
+------------+------------+--------+-------+

SELECT date,MIN(maturity) maturity FROM n GROUP BY date;
+------------+------------+
| date       | maturity   |
+------------+------------+
| 2021-07-09 | 2021-09-21 |
| 2021-07-12 | 2021-09-21 |
| 2021-07-13 | 2021-09-21 |
| 2021-07-14 | 2021-09-21 |
+------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

...

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM n a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT date,MIN(maturity) maturity FROM n GROUP BY date)b 
    ON b.date = a.date 
   AND b.maturity = a.maturity;
+------------+------------+--------+-------+
| maturity   | date       | ticker | rate  |
+------------+------------+--------+-------+
| 2021-09-21 | 2021-07-09 | SEP21  | 4.476 |
| 2021-09-21 | 2021-07-12 | SEP21  | 4.372 |
| 2021-09-21 | 2021-07-13 | SEP21  | 4.323 |
| 2021-09-21 | 2021-07-14 | SEP21  | 4.324 |
+------------+------------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your help JS Bach, however it's throwing the following error when I try to use it:

"The multi-part identifier "a.maturity" could not be bound."

Comment: Ignore my question, I've found the solution in stackoverflow database, thanks a lot!